# TortoiseSVN does not filter QT GeneratedFiles Folder as ignorelist

Tags: c++, qt, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I have some QT projects..
and i want to commit to my svn server with TortoiseSVN Client under windows 8.1.

If i put "GeneratedFiles" as ignorelist in the main TortoiseSVN Setting, then i should not get any files under "GeneratedFiles" in the commit list, or?

How can i ignore all the files under "GeneratedFiles" folder in TortoiseSVN?

I have already tried "GeneratedFiles" "[Gg]enerated[Ff]iles" "*/GeneratedFiles"..
but it does not work!

How do i have to set ignorelist for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your folder is already under version control: `right click GeneratedFiles folder > TortoiseSVN > Unversion and add to ignore list... > GeneratedFiles(recursively).`

When you try to commit you will see that *GeneratedFiles* and it's content will be deleted in SVN repo and parent folder will have the modification of `svn:global-ignores` property.

If your folder is not under version control: `right click GeneratedFiles folder > TortoiseSVN > Add to ignore list... > GeneratedFiles(recursively)`

When you try to commit you will see that parent folder will have the modification of `svn:global-ignores`.

Comment: i have "some" projects.. shoud i do this first for every each project? i thought that i should put the string "GeneratedFiles" only once in TortoiseSVN settings ignore-list..

Comment: @jung: Adding GeneratedFiles string to TortoiseSVN "global ignore list" should work just fine (I have tried this under Win 8.1, TortoiseSVN 1.8.10). But this setting in "global ignore list" will newer work on items that are already versioned (I guess that they are at least already added, otherwise, they would not appear in commit list anyway). Is that your case?

Comment: @ Ivan Jovovic: Yes. Thas was it. Thank you!